# Warning makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
dont know how to correct, any suggestion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_strncmp(char const *s1, char const *s2, int n);

int main (int ac, char **ag) {
    char result;

    if (ac == 4) {
        result = my_strncmp(ag[1], ag[2], ag[3]);
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }   
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert `ag[3]` (of type `char *` / string) to an integer.

Have a look at [`strtol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and its brethren. With [`atoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) exists a simpler function, which however is not as robust and versatile. That is why I would recommend getting into the habit of using `strtol()` et al., always.

Sidenote, "`n`" parameters are usually made `size_t` (unsigned) instead of `int`. (Compare [`strncmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp)). You'd use `strtoul()` then.

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of my_strncmp is defined as an int n, yet when it is called in main the third parameter is char * type

Answer (score 0):

in here,

```
int my_strncmp(char const *s1, char const *s2, int n);
```

the last part is `int n`

```
result = my_strncmp(ag[1], ag[2], ag[3]);
```

but here what you are passing `ag[3]` is of type char

hope this helps..